# Is there some use case addressable only by PropertyValueFactory?

Tags: java, javafx, tablecolumn

Below are three ways to assign a `CellValueFactory` to a `TableColumn` in JavaFX. The first one uses an anonymous class, the second one a lambda and the third one a `PropertyValueFactory` .

My question is about the third way, using a `PropertyValueFactory`.

Having examined the source code:

[PropertyValueFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.java)

I can't see what advantage is conferred by using this class.

In the source code of [PropertyValueFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.java), there is a note that they "try to improve performance in large tables" by caching a  '[PropertyReference](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/property/PropertyReference.java#PropertyReference)' member variable. In connection with this note, a reference to RT-13937 is mentioned. I cannot find this RT online anymore.

The following things are confused in my mind.

Is there some specific use case that is addressed by using the `PropertyValueFactory` technique that cannot be addressed using either of the other two techniques?

Is the caching of the `PropertyReference` member variable meant to address the slowness of using the `PropertyValueFactory` class in large tables, that slowness being caused by that class's use of reflection, or is  'PropertyValueFactory' class itself meant  to address the slowness of large tables generally?

```java
 /**
   First using an anonymous class
    */

        TableColumn<Person,String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person,String>("First Name");

         firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Person, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
             public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Person, String> p) {
                 // p.getValue() returns the Person instance for a particular TableView row
                 return p.getValue().firstNameProperty();
             }
          });


    /**Second using lambda
    */


        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol =new TableColumn<>("First Name");

        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());


    /**Finally using PropertyValue
    */
        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol =new TableColumn<>("First Name");

        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
```

Comment: It was the only non-verbose way to do this in Java 7. In Java 8 and later, it’s pretty much redundant.

Comment: Anonymus classes result in more `.class` files. Lambdas should result in a bigger class file. The size of the bytecode should be the smallest using `PropertyValueFactory`...

Comment: For your reference and context, the RT-13937 bug was migrated the jdk bug tracker: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8112885 and references an Oracle forum issue thread: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2232797.

Comment: James_D Thank you! I find it helpful to know how other devs consider APIs in detail..

Comment: jewelsea: thank you for the link ! Extremely useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your use case, there isn't any *significant* differences using `PropertyValueFactory` over using lambda/anonymous classes.

As far as I know these are the reasons for using `PropertyValueFactory`:

1. It's shorter and supposedly more convenient, though I find using lambda isn't that much longer either.
2. It has caching, like what you have mentioned, but it is for non-JavaFX properties (i.e. using reflections).

Therefore if you are looking for use-case for `PropertyValueFactory`, then the most fitting use-case is when your properties are normal POJO properties.

Consider this:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public final String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
    public final void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }

    public final String getLastName() { return lastName; }
    public final void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }
}

TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Person, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Person, String> p) {
        return new SimpleStringProperty(getPropertyReflectively(p.getValue(), "firstName", String.class));
    }
});

private static <T> T getPropertyReflectively(Object bean, String propertyName, Class<T> propertyType) {
    // Implementation to get property value reflectively
}
```

So there are two things observed:

1. You need to write your own messy reflection stuff. It can be done, but why would want to do that when `PropertyValueFactory` does that for you?
2. You are returning a *new instance* of `StringProperty`, and also doing reflection every time you scroll your big one-million-entry table.

I believe the caching mentioned is used for observation #2. You can continue to "decipher" the codes if you want to be sure, because I definitely didn't attempt to do so.

Comment: Came across this question looking for something else, but I'd just like to mention it's possible to use `PropertyValueFactory` in FXML files. Though I still prefer lambdas (in code) as it's type-safe and they avoid reflection.